# Persist method is not working

Tags: rest, jpa, jaxb, persistence, jersey-2.0

I have problems with JPA methods. I'm following CustomerDB Netbeans tutorial (https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html). The problem is that I can't store any data in the database. Persist method is execute and does not throw any exception so I suppose that persist is finishing correctly. But when I check the database any data has been inserted.

My persistence.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="CustomerDBPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>entities.Customer</class>
    <class>entities.MicroMarket</class>
    <class>entities.DiscountCode</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://192.168.29.130:3306/sample"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="cosio"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="316723"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The entitie is MicroMarket.java:

```
package entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

@Entity
@Table(name = "micro_market")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "MicroMarket.findAll", query = "SELECT m FROM MicroMarket m"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "MicroMarket.findByZipCode", query = "SELECT m FROM MicroMarket m WHERE m.zipCode = :zipCode"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "MicroMarket.findByRadius", query = "SELECT m FROM MicroMarket m WHERE m.radius = :radius"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "MicroMarket.findByAreaLength", query = "SELECT m FROM MicroMarket m WHERE m.areaLength = :areaLength"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "MicroMarket.findByAreaWidth", query = "SELECT m FROM MicroMarket m WHERE m.areaWidth = :areaWidth")})
public class MicroMarket implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "zip_code")
    private String zipCode;
    // @Max(value=?)  @Min(value=?)//if you know range of your decimal fields consider using these annotations to enforce field validation
    @Column(name = "radius")
    private Double radius;
    @Column(name = "area_length")
    private Double areaLength;
    @Column(name = "area_width")
    private Double areaWidth;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "zip")
    private Collection<Customer> customerCollection;

    public MicroMarket() {
    }

    public MicroMarket(String zipCode) {
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }

    public String getZipCode() {
        return zipCode;
    }

    public void setZipCode(String zipCode) {
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }

    public Double getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }

    public void setRadius(Double radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public Double getAreaLength() {
        return areaLength;
    }

    public void setAreaLength(Double areaLength) {
        this.areaLength = areaLength;
    }

    public Double getAreaWidth() {
        return areaWidth;
    }

    public void setAreaWidth(Double areaWidth) {
        this.areaWidth = areaWidth;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<Customer> getCustomerCollection() {
        return customerCollection;
    }

    public void setCustomerCollection(Collection<Customer> customerCollection) {
        this.customerCollection = customerCollection;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (zipCode != null ? zipCode.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof MicroMarket)) {
            return false;
        }
        MicroMarket other = (MicroMarket) object;
        if ((this.zipCode == null && other.zipCode != null) || (this.zipCode != null && !this.zipCode.equals(other.zipCode))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "entities.MicroMarket[ zipCode=" + zipCode + " ]";
    }

}
```

My MicroMarketFacadeRest is:

```
package entities.service;

import entities.MicroMarket;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@javax.ejb.Stateless
@Path("entities.micromarket")
public class MicroMarketFacadeREST extends AbstractFacade<MicroMarket> {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "CustomerDBPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("CustomerDBPU");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager(); 
        return em;
        //return em;
    }

    public MicroMarketFacadeREST() {
        super(MicroMarket.class);
    }


    @POST
    @Path("persisting")
    public Response persisting() {
        MicroMarket testZip = new MicroMarket("10097");
        testZip.setRadius(1987.854);
        testZip.setAreaLength(975.875);
        testZip.setAreaWidth(865.681);
        EntityTransaction tx = getEntityManager().getTransaction();
        try {
            tx.begin();
            getEntityManager().persist(testZip);
            tx.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.rollback();
        }
        throw e;
        } finally {
            getEntityManager().close();
    }
        return Response.status(200).entity("Persist is finishing").build();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public MicroMarket find(@PathParam("id") String id) {
        return super.find(id);
    }

    @GET
    @Override
    @Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public List<MicroMarket> findAll() {
        return super.findAll();
    }

}
```

And my AbstractFacade.java:

```
package entities.service;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {
    private Class<T> entityClass;

    public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

    public void create(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    }

    public void edit(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().merge(entity);
    }

    public void remove(T entity) {
        //getEntityManager().remove(entity);
        getEntityManager().remove(getEntityManager().merge(entity));
    }

    public T find(Object id) {
        System.out.println("Id of Customer requesteddddddddd" + id);
        System.out.println(id);
        System.out.println(entityClass);
        System.out.println("El puto objeto no esta vacio!!!");
        //return getEntityManager().find(entityClass, (Integer)id);
        return getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);
    }

    public List<T> findAll() {
        //EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("CustomerDBPU");
        //EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager(); 
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
        return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    }

    public List<T> findRange(int[] range) {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
            cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
        javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        q.setMaxResults(range[1] - range[0] + 1);
        q.setFirstResult(range[0]);
        return q.getResultList();
    }

    public int count() {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        javax.persistence.criteria.Root<T> rt = cq.from(entityClass);
        cq.select(getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().count(rt));
        javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        return ((Long) q.getSingleResult()).intValue();
    }

}
```

So the problem is that method persisting() is execute correctly without exceptions but in the database data has not been inserted. However find and findAll are executed correctly and returns MicroMarket correctly from the database and also in logs I can view this:

```
[EL Fine]: sql: 2015-01-02 19:12:14.017--ServerSession(206951341)--Connection(496870266)--Thread(Thread[http-nio-8084-exec-81,5,main])--SELECT zip_code, area_length, area_width, radius FROM micro_market
```

Could anybody help me? Any comment is greatly appreciated. Thanks so much.

Comment: You're using EJBs. The whole point of EJBs is that they handle transactions, declaratively, for you. So you should not start and commit transactions programmatically like you're doing. A method of a stateless bean is transactional by default. The container commits the transaction automatically after the method returns. But of course, for that to work, the transaction-type should not be set to RESOURCE_LOCAL, but to JTA. Also use dependeny injection to get an EntityManager, instead of calling a method.

Comment: Below the persit invoke the method getEntityManager().flush() and look if any exception will appear.

Comment: Hello 
uaiHebert thank you for your help. Yes, If I insert getEntityManager().flush() just after getEntityManager().persist(testZip) an exception is thrown: -> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke El Servlet.service() para el servlet [entities.service.ApplicationConfig] en el contexto con ruta [/CustomerDB] lanzó la excepción [javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: 
Exception Description: No transaction is currently active] con causa raíz
 javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: 
Exception Description: No transaction is currently active

Comment: I believe that you have something wrong in your code logic. You have the create method in the abstract facade, but you are not using it. Why do you need the injected entity manager and the getEntityManager()? Use only one, maybe this is causing you problems.

Comment: I know that, I'm only testing all the ways. Otherwise I place the persist call inside a function in abstract facade but it is not working. When persist is executed there is no exception and seems to work correctly but in the database persisted data hasn't been inserted. The last Tomcat log seems to say that persist has executed without any problem: [EL Finest]: transaction: 2015-01-02 21:28:30.435--UnitOfWork(1758409004)--Thread(Thread[http-nio-8084-exec-18,5,main])--persist() operation called on: entities.MicroMarket[ zipCode=10098 ].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Side note: you can import eclipselinks in tomee (even in your war) and it will work. About openjpa you dont seem to use jpa 2.1 features so just changing the namespace and jpa version to 2.0 will work.

Answer (score 0):

the main error was that my rest service was running on Apache Tomcat and this has no support for EJB. I try it with TomEE but I have the same problems with persist method. By default TomEE has OpenJPA instead of EclipseLink. Finally I try to deploy my App on GlassFish and now all is running correctly.